# Returning searched secondary ID rows, based on ID which can have more than one secondary ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A has ID, secondary ID, customer name, record date.

Table A ID can sometimes have a different secondary ID for the same customer.

Table B has ID and can join on Table A with this ID.

Table B has ID and description.

A user searches for a customer by the secondary ID found in Table A.

I need to create some Table C or results which return all of the data from Table A, in addition to the data from Table B after joining on their ID, but with the criteria that I also need to consider the different secondary IDs and only include the latest record across the ID and secondary IDs.

For example, secondary IDs 123, 234, and 987 are the same person (Jane). Let's say she gets married but for some of her records, that may not be updated (Hence ID: 1 and Secondary ID: 234 has names Jane Doe and Jane Brown).

**Table A:**

```
|ID|Secondary ID|Customer First Name|Customer Last Name|Record  |
|--|------------|-------------------|------------------|--------|
|1 |123         |Jane               |Doe               |02/03/20|
|1 |123         |Jane               |Doe               |01/02/20|
|1 |234         |Jane               |Brown             |04/01/21|
|1 |234         |Jane               |Doe               |05/01/21|
|1 |987         |Jane               |Doe               |03/04/21|
|2 |567         |Jack               |Brown             |01/28/21|
|2 |567         |Jack               |Brown             |06/01/21|
```

**Table B:**

```
|ID|Description     |
|--|----------------|
|1 |A description   |
|2 |Some description|
```

If a user searches for the secondary ID for 123 for Jane Doe, her actual latest record is under secondary ID 234 with the last record date being 05/01/21.
I need to return that record whenever a user searches for the ID 123, which should be displayed from that user's search and not 234.

**Results:**

```
|ID|Secondary ID|Customer First Name|Customer Last Name|Record|Description|
|--|------------|-------------------|------------------|--------|----------------|
|1 |123         |Jane               |Doe               |05/01/21|A description   |
```

Additionally, If someone searches for a secondary ID which only has one ID to it, it just needs to return that latest record.

Ex. User searches for 567. Results should be:

```
|ID|Secondary ID|Customer First Name|Customer Last Name|Record|Description|
|--|------------|-------------------|------------------|--------|----------------|
|2 |567         |Jack               |Brown             |06/01/21|Some description|
```

How can I make this possible?

Comment: and what should happen if 123 has two different names? like 234

Comment: It should be the same scenario as long as the person is the same. The ID is the primary key here. Just need the latest record date for the customer on some search of the secondary ID even if that searched secondary ID is not the one with the latest record, with the ability to also consider if that secondary ID also matches to some primary ID (ie. ID: 1 having 123, 234, 978 as possible secondary IDs).

Comment: This seems like a database normalization problem. The name should be in a customer table, not in each row of table A. When they change their name, you update it in one place and it gets reflected in all uses of the customer ID.

Comment: that malkes no sense as bith can have different dates, and an alghorithym can choose the right one, so you would get two results or even more

Comment: Unfortunately do not have control of the database that may present this issue for the database normalization, only trying to consider this as a possibility and to report any discrepancies as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT          A.ID, A.SecondaryID, A.CustomerFisrtName, A.CustomerLastName, A2.Record, B.Description
FROM            table_a AS A
    LEFT JOIN   table_b AS B ON B.ID = A.ID
    LEFT JOIN   table_a AS A2 ON A2.ID = (
                    SELECT          A3.ID
                    FROM            table_a AS A3
                    WHERE           A3.ID = A.ID
                    ORDER BY        A3.Record DESC
                    LIMIT           1
                )
WHERE           A.SecondaryID = 123;
```

Presence of an AUTO INCREMENT primary key with a normalization would have made this query way faster and simpler.